# can't find android app on emulator

Tags: android, sdk, emulation

My application has

```
android:minSdkVersion = 10
android:targetSdkVersion = 14
```

When I run it with an sdk14 emulator it works fine, but when I run with anything else (13, 12 ,11, 10) the emulator opens fine but my app is not visibly listed anywhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing your 
     android:targetSdkVersion = 14

That is most likely the code that only cause it to target 14 instead of the minimum.